# Import database into MySQL database

Tags: sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have a (.mdf) file generated from a MS-SQL server 2005 and now I want to convert that database to MySQL. However, not entirely but only specific tables with their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Problem through MYSQL Migration
First make the ODBC MS-SQL Driver then Import database From MS-SQL server with Complete data

Answer (score 0):

The .mdf file is not fit for your purpose. It's better to export your table data using SQL Server's Bulk copy program BCP and then to import using MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE.

From the [Mysql migration guide](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/):

> For those using SQL Server who are not familiar with Integration Services, it is possible to move data from SQL Server to MySQL using a combination of the SQL Server bulk copy program (BCP) and the MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE utility. A DBA can create data files with SQL Server BCP where the data is delimited by an appropriate character (such as a comma, semi-colon, etc.) and then load the data into MySQL with LOAD DATA INFILE with the same delimiter being specified.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench has a migration module exactly for that scenario. You don't need to create an mdf file, but you can directly migrate whole databases or indiviudal tables from MS SQL to MySQL. Alternatively you can export your data to a CSV file and import that with the table importer (you need at least MySQL Workbench 6.3 for that, which is available as RC atm and soon available as GA).

Comment: I've done this using MYSQL Workbench Migration Module .... and Thanks my dear so much :)

Comment: Shahzad, if you find my answer help then please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left hand side. You may even upvote it, if it provided you addtiional benefit.

Comment: On the left hand side, right under the vote counter (which is currently 0) and the 2 arrows to upvote/downvote. You have very low reputation atm, so the screen might look a bit different for you, but you should at least be able to accept an answer to your own question.